# find multiple time overlaps

Tags: php, mysql

i have to check some times overlap in mysql with a specific time plans
like:

```
time_plan1 = 2011-06-30, startTime = 09:00:00, finishTime = 10:00:00
time_plan2 = 2011-06-30, startTime = 12:30:00, finishTime = 13:30:00
time_plan3 = 2011-06-30, startTime = 14:00:00, finishTime = 15:30:00
time_plan4 = 2011-06-30, startTime = 17:00:00, finishTime = 18:00:00
```

and times

```
time1 = 2011-06-30, startTime = 08:30:00, finishTime = 10:00:00
time2 = 2011-06-30, startTime = 12:30:00, finishTime = 13:30:00
time3 = 2011-06-30, startTime = 14:00:00, finishTime = 15:00:00
time4 = 2011-06-30, startTime = 16:30:00, finishTime = 19:00:00
```

so i have to find the overlaps between time plans and times for each couple of time plan and times but i cant specified which time is belong to which time plan

## update

for result i need to have the sum of times those belong to time plans
in this case :
time1 : 1h
time2 : 1h
time3 : 1h
time4 : 1h
sum for 2011-06-30 : 4h

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: yes! but no lucky. "select * *** WHERE time1.startTime> time_plan1.startTime and time1.finishTime < time_plan1.finishTime" but the employee maybe no ontime to start time or finish time...

Comment: Can you show how the data is pulled/stored?

Comment: @rob W : `INSERT INTO `work_plan` (`wpid`, `user_id`, `day`, `stime`, `entime`, `status`, `add_date`) VALUES
(2, 1, 1, 660, 1020, 'pending', '2013-06-23 12:18:36'),
(3, 1, 1, 660, 1020, 'pending', '2013-06-23 12:20:08'),
(5, 1, 1, 960, 1200, 'pending', '2013-06-23 12:21:50'),
(6, 1, 1, 960, 975, 'reqdel', '2013-06-23 12:22:12');`

Comment: and `INSERT INTO `work_time` (`wtid`, `user_id`, `year`, `month`, `day`, `hour`, `min`, `sec`, `full_time`, `status`, `by`) VALUES
(101, 1, 1390, 11, 9, 14, 12, 56, 1327833776, 'auto', 0),
(577, 1, 1390, 11, 26, 18, 39, 38, 1329318578, 'auto', 0),
(578, 1, 1390, 11, 26, 18, 41, 21, 1329318681, 'auto', 0);`

Comment: Can you add to your question what results you would like to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you ace
your response helped me to find the answer..
to save in history

```
foreach($plan as $wpk=>$pla){
       foreach($work as $wtk=>$wor){
        if($wor['start']<$pla['end'] and $wor['end']>$pla['start']){
          $overlap_start = max($wor['start'],$pla['start']);
          $overlap_finis = min($wor['end'], $pla['end']);
          $sum +=  $overlap_finis - $overlap_start;
          if($overlap_start>$wor['start'])
          $work[] = array('start'=>$wor['start'],'end'=>$overlap_start);
          if($wor['end']>$overlap_finis)
          $work[] = array('start'=>$overlap_finis,'end'=>$wor['end']);
          unset($work["$wtk"]);
                     }
                   }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE time1.startTime > time_plan1.startTime and time1.finishTime < time_plan1.finishTime
```

This is almost correct, but you only get the scenario where the time starts later than the time plan, and the time finishes earlier than the time plan.

To get the overlaps,

```
WHERE time1.startTime < time_plan1.startTime or time1.finishTime > time_plan1.finishTime
```

What this does is catch this 3 overlapping scenarios

- time starts earlier than startTime, but finishes later than finishTime
- time starts earlier than startTime and also finishes earlier than finishTime
- time starts later than startTime, but finishes later than finishTime

The tricky part is getting the sum of the overlaps, which I think you'll need `PHP` for since this will be complicated being handled by `sql`.

Assuming you've received your records with the startTime and finishTime fields for the time and time plans.

```
$sum = 0; // seconds
foreach ($records as $record) {
  $overlap_start = max($record->time_startTime, $record->timeplan_startTime);
  $overlap_finish = min($record->time_finishTime, $record->timeplan_finishTime);
  $sum += strtotime($overlap_finish) - strtotime($overlap_start);
}
```

Comment: thank you but when i think more to your solution ,i get more confounded! when use `or` in query `WHERE time1.startTime < time_plan1.startTime or time1.finishTime > time_plan1.finishTime` it return all records for each days because all records have lower starttime or upper finishtime!! but at first we must find the overlapped times then go to php to calculate sum!

Comment: ah, sorry. i think you must include the date as well.